# cocoapods lib lint error [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, podspec

when i use a framework in my podspec appear this error, how can i fix it ???

ld: illegal text-relocation to 'cstring' in /Users/XY/Desktop/AJKPlayer/AJKPlayer/Frameworks/wplayer.framework/wplayer(alphablend.o) from '_ff_sws_alphablendaway' in /Users/XY/Desktop/AJKPlayer/AJKPlayer/Frameworks/wplayer.framework/wplayer(alphablend.o) for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)